# Gtk+ and OpenGL bindings

Tags: c, opengl, gtk

Simple and short: **What is the most advanced OpenGL binding for GTK+?**
I would prefer a widget which allows me to use it similar to QGLWidget.

Note: I stumbled upon gtkglext, gtkglarea and clutter. I read the first two have shortcomings/ serious issues.

Comment: They seem to both be activly developed, with releases in 2009 and 2010, and recent activity (http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkglext/ , http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkglarea/) Which one to prefer, I can't tell though - but I wouldn't judge it entierly on how recent a release is..

Comment: There was a dedictated side for gtkglext which told me it was 2006. Maybe it was soom google-voodoo resurecting a removed side from its overwritten bits. QUestion edited accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**

**Since `Gtk+-3.16` any beyond do *not* use any of the below!**

If you want to use the current state of the art, vertex/pixel shaders you should use the latest gnome and rely on its caps:

Extensively covered in https://www.bassi.io/articles/2015/02/17/using-opengl-with-gtk/

---

Ok, I read pretty much through the last 2 hours and my results are:

- **gtkglext** will completly replace the backend by OpenGL, this was not my intention
- **clutter** has all native gl calls boxed into objects and does not support native gl calls *at all*, though it provides many predifened filters and *funny stuff*
- **gtkglarea** seems fine, its design is lovely. It has the same usage style as QGLWidget in Qt (as far as I can say) [simple demo of gtkglarea](http://www.gamgi.org/simple.c):

  ```
  #include <math.h>
  #include <gtk/gtk.h>
  #include <GL/gl.h>
  #include <gtkgl/gtkglarea.h>

  int init (GtkWidget *widget)
  {
  if (gtk_gl_area_make_current (GTK_GL_AREA(widget)))
    {
    glViewport(0,0, widget->allocation.width, widget->allocation.height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,100, 100,0, -1,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    }

  return TRUE;
  }

  int draw (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event)
  {
  if (event->count > 0) return TRUE;

  if (gtk_gl_area_make_current (GTK_GL_AREA(widget)))
    {
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(10,10);
    glVertex2f(10,90);
    glVertex2f(90,90);
    glEnd();
    gtk_gl_area_swap_buffers (GTK_GL_AREA(widget));
    }

  return TRUE;
  }

  int reshape (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventConfigure *event)
  {
  if (gtk_gl_area_make_current (GTK_GL_AREA(widget)))
    glViewport(0,0, widget->allocation.width, widget->allocation.height);

  return TRUE;
  }

  int main (int argc, char **argv)
  {
  GtkWidget *window, *glarea;

  int attrlist[] = {
  GDK_GL_RGBA,
  GDK_GL_RED_SIZE,1,
  GDK_GL_GREEN_SIZE,1,
  GDK_GL_BLUE_SIZE,1,
  GDK_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER,
  GDK_GL_NONE };

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
  if (gdk_gl_query () == FALSE) return 0;

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW(window), "Simple");
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
  g_signal_connect (window, "delete_event",
  G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  /* You should always delete gtk_gl_area widgets before exit or else
     GLX contexts are left undeleted, this may cause problems (=core dump)
     in some systems.
     Destroy method of objects is not automatically called on exit.
     You need to manually enable this feature. Do gtk_quit_add_destroy()
     for all your top level windows unless you are certain that they get
     destroy signal by other means. */

  gtk_quit_add_destroy (1, GTK_OBJECT(window));

  glarea = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_gl_area_new (attrlist));
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (GTK_WIDGET(glarea), 100, 100);

  gtk_widget_set_events (GTK_WIDGET(glarea), GDK_EXPOSURE_MASK | GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

  g_signal_connect (glarea, "expose_event", G_CALLBACK(draw), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (glarea, "configure_event", G_CALLBACK(reshape), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (glarea, "realize", G_CALLBACK(init), NULL);

  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), GTK_WIDGET(glarea));
  gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET(glarea));
  gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET(window));

  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
  }
  ```

Note: gtkglarea has still some problems like core dump on exit (at least 1.99)

Note2: Version 2.0.1 fixes this issue

Edit: For those seeking for 2D only **cairo** seems to be most suitable.

Comment: the widgets themselfs will be rendered via OpenGL, as you can easily obtain from http://projects.gnome.org/gtkglext/